# Incorrect passport number written on UAE visa. Can I still travel?

Tags: visas, uae

I applied for a visa to travel to Dubai. It was approved but, later, I noticed the passport number error written on the visa. The passport number is incorrect: it was written as '6' but it is supposed to be the number 5.

What do I have to do? Do I need to re-apply for a new visa or I can it be corrected?

Comment: What do you mean by "mismatch"? Is it a completely different number or a number from your previous passport?

Comment: Most embassies allow correction of visas gratis (for free) when the error is made by the embassy. Notify them first and then they will likely make you aware the exact procedure so you don't pay before asking for a refund. Governments don't like giving refunds.

Comment: Call the UAE embassy or the phone number mentioned at the bottom of the e-visa. If they cant fix, most likely you have to apply for a new one. If you notice at the bottom of e-visa, there are notes which say `This permit becomes invalid if any alteration occurs in details`

Comment: The last passport number was in correct, suppose number 5, it was written number 6.

Answer (score 2):

**Tread very carefully**

As someone who lived in Abu Dhabi and Dubai for the last eight years, any snafu with passports and visas can create an issue.   It seems to always be one of two extremes: I've walked in without even showing my passport (although they've tightened that up a bit), and I've been detained overnight because my passport had a little wear-and-tear.

Contact the UAE Embassy in your country and ask what they recommend you do.  Most likely they can re-issue it very quickly (it might depend on your circumstances).  As a rule of thumb anywhere, if they say it's fine as it is, I always like to call later and ask again - just to get a second opinion.

Happy and safe travels - get over there before summer comes.

Answer (score 1):

Anecdotal evidence suggests that it might be wiser to get this corrected prior to travelling, to avoid any issues or delays. In similar circumstances, some report that they were prevented from boarding by the airline, others that they were either detained or refused by Immigration upon arrival.

You don't mention where you made your visa application, but your first step should be to contact the service through which you applied.

Another option would be to contact the '[AMER service](http://www.amer.ae/New/ContactUsDefault.asp)' of the General Directorate of Residency and Foreigners Affairs-Dubai, for answers to queries about visas for any of the emirates.

The 24-hour service offers several communication options, such as toll-free number (voice), fax, e-mail and e-chat.

Toll free: 800 5111
Tel (Int.): +971 4 313 9999
Fax: +9714 5011111
E-Mail: amer@dnrd.ae
[E-Chat](http://amer.ae/amerchat.htm): available from 10.00 am to 5.00 pm (EST), Sunday through Thursday; 2 pm GMT - 9 pm GMT.

[UAE Visa Service Centres Abroad](https://www.mofa.gov.ae/EN/ConsularServices/Pages/Visa-Information.aspx)

Visa centre in Colombo - Sri Lanka:
112, Kumarathunga Munidasa Mawatha, Colombo
Phone : 0094112554777
Fax : 0094112554774
Email: conscolombo@mofa.gov.ae
Opening hours Monday to Friday from 9 am – 4 pm

Visa Centre in Sri Lanka - Indonesia:
Menara Prima 2, Podium Arcade Floor
Block 6.3 Lingkar Mega Kuningan Jak-Sel
Phone : +6221-25985500
Fax : +6221-57940086/7
Email: consoffice.jakarta@mofa.gov.ae
Opening hours Monday to Friday from 9 am – 4 pm

Visa Centre in Nairobi - Kenya:
Nyerere Road P.O. Box 42222
 
00100 Nairobi
Phone : +254709991777
Email: Nairobi@mofa.gov.ae
Opening hours Monday to Friday  from 9 am – 4 pm

Visa Centre in Dhaka - Bangladesh 
Empori Financial - Road #93 plot #6 
Ground floor Gulshan North Avenue, Dhaka
Phone: +8809609111000
Email: consdhaka@mofa.gov.ae
Opening hours Sunday to Thursday, from 9 am – 4 pm

Visa Centre in Cairo  -  Egypt
Block 77, Street 90, Fifth Settlement
New Cairo, near Al-Ahly Bank
Phone : +2 0226730000 - +2 0226730004
Email: conscairo@mofa.gov.ae
Opening hours Sunday to Thursday, from 8 am – 3 pm

Visa Centre in New Delhi – India 
Ground Floor, Ambience Commercial Complex
(Ambience Tower), Vasant Kunj
Phone : +91 11 3921 7555
Email: consular.newdelhi@mofa.gov.ae
Opening hours from Monday to Friday 9 am – 4 pm

Visa Centre in Tunis – Tunis
Panorama Building, Bourse Street, Lake 2, Tunis
Phone : +216 71100700
Email: constunis@mofa.gov.ae
Opening hours from Monday to Friday  8 am – 3 pm